# Why does Matlab provide an arbitrary constant of integration?

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I'm integrating the following expression:

sin(2*x)/4 - 8*sin(x)

In Matlab, I put in

```
syms x
int(sin(2*x)/4 - 8*sin(x))
```

and it returns

```
17*cos(x/2)^2 - cos(x/2)^4
```

In [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(sin(2*x)%2F4%20-%208*sin(x))), I input

```
int(sin(2*x)/4 - 8*sin(x))
```

and it returns

```
8 cos(x) - 1/8 cos(2 x) + constant
```

For the sake of comparing the two solutions, I put the following into [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(sin(2*x)%2F4%20-%208*sin(x))%20%3D%3D%2017*cos(x%2F2)%5E2%20-%20cos(x%2F2)%5E4)

```
int(sin(2*x)/4 - 8*sin(x)) == 17*cos(x/2)^2 - cos(x/2)^4
```

and it shows Matlab's solution gives a constant of integration `65/8`, whereas Wolfram leaves the constant of integration arbitrary. I'm glad I caught this because it makes a big difference in my final solution, albeit a constant. My question is, why does Matlab feel the need to provide a constant of integration, when in the end it's arbitrary? Seems kinda dangerous.

Comment: fwiw mathematica gives `8 Cos[x] - 1/8 Cos[2 x]` (no explicit constant, since like matlab if you are expected to read the docs and understand it is giving you an antiderivative, and antiderivatives are non-unique within arbitrary constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`int` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html), "Results returned by int do not include integration constants".  But clearly, some got introduced during the solution.  So I guess a better statement would be: MATLAB doesn't introduce any new symbolic constants to the solution if one is found (unlike WolframAlpha implies but like Mathematica).

However, apparently, definite arbitrary constants introduced to, and possibly hidden in, the solution may be introduced by the solution algorithm.  This is perfectly valid since an indefinite integral yields an infinite number of valid solutions sans initial or terminal data.

According to the [MuPAD documentation of `int`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html) (MATLAB's symbolic engine), indefinite integrals are tackled via "table lookup or Risch integration", and I'm sure that's after some front-end parsing and simplification beforehand to boot.  So whichever branch of the decision tree the symbolic engine went down ended up producing powers of trigonometric functions which indicate the introduction of constants upon their reduction.  I don't know if this is standard practice. But I can see how giving the algorithm some leeway to introduce such constants may be beneficial for a robust solution method since symbolic indefinite integration is an extremely difficult task.

So to try and answer the question: "why does Matlab feel the need to provide a constant of integration, when in the end it's arbitrary?"  It does it because it can, and the underlying algorithm determined it was the right course of action for some reason.  Also, the solution is perfectly valid since it is arbitrary.

"Seems kinda dangerous."  I would disagree.  While not entirely ideal, the results of the integration will be correct once the appropriate data is introduced and used in tandem with the solution.  If no such appropriate data exists, the problem is under-specified and any solution is valid to an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Sounds like you know your stuff. It sounds like there's no way to "shut it off"?

Comment: How can I get Matlab to output 8*cos(x) - 1/8*cos(2*x) + 65/8 as opposed to 17*cos(x/2)^2 - cos(x/2)^4 ? I want to see the constant of integration it's adding.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Sorry for the delay; forgot about this over the weekend.  Given the apparent complexity of symbolic indefinite integration and the lack of options in the documentation, I doubt it is something that can be turned off.  It is what it is.  As for the simplification, it may require a bit of massaging post integration but `I=int(sin(2*x)/4 - 8*sin(x));` and `rewrite(expand(simplify(rewrite(I,'exp'))),'cos')` gives the desired result.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the reply. I was afraid it would come to that. I tried a few `rewrite` and `expand` calls, but never succeeded. I'm guessing that combination you put together is problem dependent. As you said it is what it is. If I really need to know the constant, I'll check with Wolfram. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @ThatsRightJack Sorry for the late reply, I had only seen this right now. Why would you say 17*cos(x/2)^2 - cos(x/2)^4 introduces a constant but 8*cos(x) - 1/8*cos(2*x) does not? In my eyes, any solution has an arbitrary constant necessarily, and the MATLAB documentation only says there is no arbitrary “+ constant” in the result.

Now, if you want to “fix” the constant, you could use definite integration and say `f(x) = int(sin(2*x)/4 - 8*sin(x),x,0,x)`, which returns a continuous f such that `f(0)==0`. (That f happens to be `-((cos(x) - 1)*(cos(x) - 31))/4`.)